# Para quando visual do SO EN?

Tags: suporte

Alguém sabe quando a nossa comunidade vai receber o update visual muito *top* da comunidade em inglês?

Comment: Parece que não vai demorar, não acredito que tenham um prazo definido, a não ser que já esteja pra implementar aqui nos próximos dias, o que também duvido.

Comment: Só não pode é trazer um layout novo com textos sem tradução.

Comment: Eu nem sabia do novo layout. Já agora as filas de analise do SOen metem medo!

Comment: Espero que demore, não curti :/, ou que pelo menos melhorem antes de colocar em outros sites da rede.